# How can i store checkbox value to database without submit button in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am new Laravel, I'm trying to store it, but I can't. I'm going to check or uncheck the checkbox in a post model.
[image: view]
I saw a similar code at StackOverflow but I don't understand Ajax, therefore who will help me to understand the code? Sorry English is my second language.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#aksi').change(function() {
                var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
                if(returnVal){
                    postToServer($(this).prop("checked"))
                }else{
                    $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));
                }
            });
        });

        function postToServer(state){
            let value = (state) ? 1 : 0;
            alert('Posted Value: ' + value);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin/status",
                data: {"aski":value},
                success: function(response){
                    //handle response
                }
            });
```

It is blade code `<input type="checkbox" id="aksi" checked><span class="lever">`

CommentController

```
public function status($id)
{
    $comment = Comment::findOrFail($id);
    if($comment->status == 'active')
        $comment->status = 'inactive';
    else
        $comment->status = 'active';
    $comment->save();

    return back()->withSuccess(__("message.data_deleted"));
}
```

Route

```
 Route::get('/status/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'status'])->name('admin.comment.status');
```

Comment: Add your code to the question, not images of code.

Comment: Your frontend AJAX route points to `POST: admin/status` yet the shared backend route refers to `GET: /status/{id}`. This is strange. In addition, you submit `{"aski":value}` in your POST request body, yet it's never used in `CommentController::status($id)`

Comment: Firstly, fix your backend route. Secondly, make use of the POST request body data in your Controller method. With that, you should be good to go. Lastly, I hope you're sending the 'CRSF token' in your HTTP POST request, otherwise, you may face an “Invalid or missing CSRF token” message/error.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSRF in header:

```php
<meta name="CSRF-TOKEN" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

then

```js
$('#aksi').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
   if (returnVal === true) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "admin/status",
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="CSRF-TOKEN"]').attr('content')},
          data: {"aski":$(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0},
          success: function(response) {
                   //handle response
          }
      });
   } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Route:

Route must be post type and if you are not using admin prefix then add admin in url because you're using admin/status.
You also have to pass `id` in above url.

```php
Route::post('/status/{id}', [CommentController::class, 'status'])->name('admin.comment.status');
```